# OnlyNumeric Directive not working when input type = "number" in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I searched almost everything but was not possible to get the answer maybe someone here can help.
Ok first let me introduce what this directive do,,It will not allow any alphabet to enter in my input
Here my `OnlyNumeric`  directive works when my `input type = "text"`,
but it does not works when `input type = "number"`
Here is my directive

```
app.directive('onlyNumeric', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                alert();
                if (text == null) { text = ""; }
                var text = text.toString();
                var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
                if (transformedInput.length > 7) {
                    transformedInput = transformedInput.slice(0, -1);
                }
                if (transformedInput !== text) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }

                if (!isNaN(Number(transformedInput))) {
                    //   alert("decimal no");
                    return parseInt(transformedInput);
                }
                else { return transformedInput; }
                //  return transformedInput;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('is_valid', false);
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);

        }
    };
});
```

My html

```
<input type = "number" only-numeric ng-model ="age">
```

So when i change my type to "text" it works

So i tried another way to catching keydown event but , i am not getting how to catch my input values,
The line `ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);` does not pass my input until the input is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not executing the directive, you should use it with name-with-dashes notation, like this:

```
<input type="number" only-numeric ng-model="age">
```

Comment: Sorry for that,that was a typo, i edited my qts but still same output